# Exponential Family

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

I want to check  if the PDF belongs to the exponential family:

$$f(x|v) = C \exp-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_{i}-v)^4$$

How can this fit into this formula (to check if the pdf belongs to the exponential family)?

$$f(x|\theta) = h(x)c(\theta) \exp \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} w_{i}(\theta) t_{i}(x) \right)$$

Comment: For clarity, do you "want to check if the *following* PDF belongs to the exponential family"?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Are you missing some parentheses in the first density?

Comment: Ignore the sum over i, and try to show it for $p(x) \propto \exp(-(x-v)^4)$ by expanding the quartic function.